# How to clear master.dbo.sysprocesses?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I see all connection session by query statement:

```
Select * From master.dbo.sysprocesses
```

And i try to clear by statement:

```
Delete From master.dbo.sysprocesses
```

or

```
Truncate table master.dbo.sysprocesses
```

or update but not allow.

[image]

Please help me know how to clear or update
***master.dbo.sysprocesses*** ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: why would you want to do this? edit: haha, jinx

Comment: My friend connected to his teacher's database, and him afraid his teacher will know that.
So him ask me, but i don't know.
Please help him.

Comment: So your friend connected to your teacher's database without permission and now wants to cover his tracks? Good luck with that, I'm out.

Comment: don't out, please help.
Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do any `DML (Insert/Delete/Update)` or any `DDL(DROP,Truncate`) on system Catalogs.You may land in big trouble

<kbd>SysProcesses</kbd> has an entry for each session connected to the database.you can simply disconnect your session which clears your entry unless your teacher has an Audit

Comment: so, how long time to his session clear on sysprocesses?

Comment: if you are no longer connected to ssms,this will help *

Comment: if i use my computer to connect to his teacher's database, and i try connect, disconnect many times, so my friend's connection will be clear?

Answer (score 1):

If your "friend" wants to remove his connection from sys.sysprocesses, then your "friend" should disconnect, then his spid will no longer be in the list of sys.sysprocesses.  :-)

Comment: i know, but can not wait longtime, because his teacher alway check connections.
Today, his teacher busy, but maybe this night he will check :'(

Answer (score 0):

This **is not a table** it is list of OS processes running on an instance of SQL Server.
so you can do any operation on table.